# Return zero if there are no results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have trouble building a query which I think is actually quite easy...

I have a simple table where I do a simple count, and when I'm filtering the result with a date, I would like to have zeros where there's no rows instead of no result.

For example:

```
select APP_ID as APPLI, count(ID) as NB 
from ARCHIVE 
where GROUP_ID = 'Sample'
GROUP BY APP_ID
```

returns

```
A   560
B   1,178
C   9
D   643
E   4
```

and

```
select APP_ID as APPLI, count(ID) as NB 
from ARCHIVE 
where GROUP_ID = 'Sample' and TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('01/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') 
GROUP BY APP_ID
```

returns

```
B   40
D   82
E   4
```

And I would like

```
A   0
B   40
C   0
D   82
E   4
```

Some sample datas:

```
ID              APP_ID  TIMESTAMP
ARCH_1/20/216       A   2010-12-16
ARCH_1/20/218       A   2010-12-16
ARCH_1/20/219       A   2010-12-16
ARCH_1/40/28        A   2011-02-09
ARCH_1/40/29        A   2011-02-09
ARCH_1/40/30        A   2011-02-09
ARCH_1/260/9012     B   2014-04-19
ARCH_1/260/7093     B   2014-04-12
ARCH_1/260/8996     B   2014-04-19
ARCH_1/44/61        C   2011-09-12
ARCH_1/44/62        C   2011-09-13
ARCH_1/260/8382     D   2014-04-16
ARCH_1/260/6872     D   2014-04-11
ARCH_1/260/6271     D   2014-04-08
ARCH_1/260/8607     D   2014-04-17
ARCH_1/260/8998     E   2014-04-19
ARCH_1/260/9011     E   2014-04-19
```

Edit: I'm using Oracle SQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: could do something fun like a left join to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, you need a (distinct) list of **all** ids first.  In situations like this, a subquery is preferred:

```
SELECT Archive_List.app_id, COALESCE(COUNT(), 0) as NB
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT app_id
      FROM Archive) Archive_List
LEFT JOIN Archive
       ON Archive.app_id = Archive_List.app_id
          AND Archive.group_id = 'Sample'
          AND Archive.timestamp >= CAST('2014-01-01' as DATE)
GROUP BY Archive_List.app_id
```

If `timestamp` actually *is* the indicated type (and that's a **terrible** name for a column, by the way), you should be using `>=`, so you get any rows set at midnight.
This statement will work on most/all RDBMSs

Comment: I tried subqueries, I tried left join, but not tried both. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A1.APP_ID as APPLI, NVL(count(A2.ID),0) as NB 
from ARCHIVE A1 LEFT JOIN
     ARCHIVE A2 on A1.APP_ID=A2.APP_ID
where A1.GROUP_ID = 'Sample' and A1.TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('01/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') 
GROUP BY A1.APP_ID
```

Comment: I think you mean it the other way around, use `ISNULL` in SQL Server and `IFNULL` in MySQL.  **Edit:** Just saw your edit

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it returns 
B: 52,726
C: 16
D: 47,120.

Comment: @thibon: Use `NVL` for oracle.

Comment: It's not working because of course there are multiple occurrences of `APP_ID` (hence why it's in the `GROUP BY`).  You need to get a distinct list of ids first.  Oh, and prefer the ANSI standard `COALESCE(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
A2.APP_ID as APPLI,
NVL(count(A1.ID),0) as NB 
from ARCHIVE A1
RIGHT JOIN ARCHIVE A2 on A1.APP_ID = A2.APP_ID
where A1.GROUP_ID = 'Sample' and A1.TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('01/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') 
GROUP BY A2.APP_ID
```

How about this one?

---

```
WITH X AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
APP_ID
from
ARCHIVE)

SELECT
X.APP_ID
,COALESCE(count(A.ID),0)
from
X
left join ARCHIVE A on X.APP_ID = A.APP_ID
where
A1.GROUP_ID = 'Sample' and A1.TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('01/01/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') 
group by
X.APP_ID
```

Comment: Nope, also going to fail for the same reason as @RagingBull's answer.  Yours is potentially _less_ correct - you didn't change which tables had the restricted criteria, so the counts will be even more off.  The problem was **not** the join direction.

Comment: Well, at the moment it'll throw an error because you use an incorrect non-existant table alias.  But yes, the base setup is correct.  Although, your formatting could use some work...